# WCF service operations to check cache first

Tags: .net, wcf, behavior

We have an in-memory memorycache object in our WCF service. Is there a way I can decorate operations in WCF service so that the call is redirected to check cache first and after checking cache, control goes to actual operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement [IOperationInvoker](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/05/16/wcf-extensibility-ioperationinvoker/) where you can intercept the call on operation level. Operation invoker is hooked via [IOperationBehvaior](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/04/11/wcf-extensibility-ioperationbehavior/)

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about same. Are there any examples out there? Couldn't find any. I do see some examples of caching the response of an operation via operation behavior, but could not see where cache is in memory and is getting checked before calling operation (whether or not operation is called - depends on some data from cache).

Comment: If you click on the link I provided for [IOperationBehavior](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/05/16/wcf-extensibility-ioperationinvoker/) it will take you to the example that is implementing cachable operation.

Comment: Yes it seems like it will work for me. Marked your comment as answered. Thanks!